# Get rid of '\n' in Python

Tags: python

How to get rid of '\n' at the end of a line ?

Comment: What do you mean?  Do you want to print text without a newline after the printed string?  (Btw, I don't think "n" is a particularly helpful tag for this question...)

Comment: Do you mean from an input line?  When printing?

Comment: Given that your question is so vague, I believe a valid answer would be "don't put it there." Although I assume you've got helpful answers instead.

Answer (score 25):

```
"string \n".strip();
```

or

```
"string \n".rstrip();
```

Answer (score 18):

If, as Rolf suggests in his comment, you want to print text without having a newline automatically appended, use

```
print "foo",
```

Note the trailing comma.

Comment: Yeah, that may be the problem.

Answer (score 7):

Get rid of just the "\n" at the end of the line:

```
>>> "string \n".rstrip("\n")
'string '
```

Get rid of all whitespace at the end of the line:

```
>>> "string \n".rstrip()
'string'
```

Split text by lines, stripping trailing newlines:

```
>>> "line 1\nline 2 \nline 3\n".splitlines()
['line 1', 'line 2 ', 'line 3']
```

Answer (score 4):

In Python 3, to print a string without a newline, set the end to an empty string:

```
print("some string", end="")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a slightly more complex and explicit way of writing output:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write("string")
```

Then you would responsible for your own newlines.